# RxSwift PublishSubject getting unintentionally disposed

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have a View Controller that opens a modal view controller for the user to pick images from its library. For that, I'm using a Rx wrapper of `DKImagePickerController` that I wrote.

The relevant code in the View Controller is as follows:

```
fileprivate func addPicturesFromLibrary() {
    guard let viewModel = self.viewModel else { return }

    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
    pickerController.singleSelect = false
    pickerController.maxSelectableCount = 10
    pickerController.showsCancelButton = true
    pickerController.sourceType = .photo

    pickerController.rx.didSelectAssets()
        .debug(" 1")
        .bind(to: viewModel.addAssetsInput)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My view model looks like this:

```
class MediaViewModel {

      var selectedImages = Variable<[MediaListingImage]>([])

      public let addAssetsInput = PublishSubject<DKAsset>()

      init() {
         bind()
      }

      private func bind() {
          addAssetsInput
              .debug(" 2")
              .flatMap {
                  $0.rx.fetchOriginalImage()
              }
              .map {
                  MediaListingImage.local($0)
              }
              .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (mediaListingImage) in
                  self?.selectedImages.value.append(mediaListingImage)
              })
              .disposed(by: disposeBag)
      }
}
```

When I open the first modal picker, it works as expected. However, when it disposes, the binding *in the view model* also disposes, so subsequent presentations of the modal view controller won't work.

Here's the log I get in the console, which might help you understand what I see:

```
2017-11-15 17:33:15.490:  2 -> subscribed
2017-11-15 17:33:21.452:  1 -> subscribed
2017-11-15 17:33:23.902:  1 -> Event next(<DKImagePickerController.DKAsset: 0x6080002ab940>)
2017-11-15 17:33:23.902:  2 -> Event next(<DKImagePickerController.DKAsset: 0x6080002ab940>)
2017-11-15 17:33:23.902:  1 -> Event completed
2017-11-15 17:33:23.903:  2 -> Event completed
2017-11-15 17:33:23.903:  2 -> isDisposed
2017-11-15 17:33:23.903:  1 -> isDisposed
2017-11-15 17:33:29.924:  1 -> subscribed
2017-11-15 17:33:33.114:  1 -> Event next(<DKImagePickerController.DKAsset: 0x60c0002a62a0>)
2017-11-15 17:33:33.114:  1 -> Event completed
2017-11-15 17:33:33.114:  1 -> isDisposed
```

If I change the code in the View Controller to something like:

```
    pickerController.rx.didSelectAssets()
        .debug(" 1")
        .subscribe(onNext: { (asset) in
            viewModel.addAssetsInput.onNext(asset)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

it works as expected. However, I find using `bind` more elegant in this case, and would like to keep using it if possible.

What is triggering the binding of the `PublishSubject` in the view model to dispose? How can I prevent it without leaking resources?

Comment: Is `disposeBag` a property of ViewController in first snippet, and `disposeBag` in second snippet is a property of ViewModel?

Comment: @shpasta yes, both are properties of their respective classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that because the `completed` propagated through the second chain (the one in `MediaViewModel.bind`) that it will no longer receive any events. I think you'd want to use `subscribe(onNext: { ... })` here instead of `bind` so that you can avoid sending error and completion events.

Another alternative would be to use a `PublishRelay` instead of a `PublishSubject`.

> PublishRelay is a wrapper for `PublishSubject`. Unlike `PublishSubject` it can't terminate with error or completed.